# Kendo Core GridBuilder IHtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, extension-methods

I am playing with building some extension methods over the Kendo Core Extensions.

A working example -

```
public static DatePickerBuilder MyDatePicker<T>(this IHtmlHelper<T> helper)
        {
            return helper.Kendo().DatePicker().HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" });
        }
```

Implementation is

```
@(Html.MyDatePicker().Name("testDatePicker"))
```

Now... the grid... this is where I'd really like to define a bunch of standard defaults...

```
 public static GridBuilder<T> MyGridDefault<T>(this IHtmlHelper<T> helper) where T : class
        {
            return                
            helper.Kendo().Grid<T>()
            .Groupable()
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Scrollable()
            .Filterable()
            .Pageable();
        }
```

Implementation -

```
 @(Html.MyGridDefault<Person>()
                .Name("TestGrid1")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                  columns.Bound(c => c.LastName);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName);
                })
                .BindTo(people)
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                ))
```

This throws an error -

> IHtmlHelper(DashboardViewModel) does not contain a definition for
> 'MyGridDefault' and the best extension method overload
> 'MyKendoExtensions.MyGridDefault(IHtmlHelper)'
> requires a receiver of type 'IHtmlHelper'
>
> NOTE: I substituted  () for <> after IHtmlHelper.  I can't remember how to escape this...

DashboardViewModel is the model the view is typed to.  So, I think I am understanding that the IHtmlHelper, T is either the model of the view, or some type of base in Core when they view is not typed to a model?

What is interesting is the implementation does not complain in the column binding... so the implemented Grid is seeing that it is binding to a person... but I can't compile due the IHtmlHelper error.  I am new to Core, and thus Kendo on core... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the non-generic version: `(this HtmlHelper helper)`

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the suggestion... I did try that originally... it produces the same issue.

Comment: [Kendo forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-grid-html-helper) suggests trying `MyGridDefault<T>(this GridBuilder<T> helper)`

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Steve.  Your suggestion produces the same produces the same error, just now substitute with "required a receiver Type of GridBuilder<Person>...  still not progress here

Comment: I don't think this works in .NET Core